# TCP Connection to Pure Data with Blender Python

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, blender, puredata

I need some help figuring out my code for sending info from Blender through TCP connection to Pure Data. I have a surface with a ball rolling around on it and I need to grab the speed of the ball and its collisions in order to send it over TCP to Pd in order to convert data into procedural audio.

I have been looking at possible ways of doing this and due to my very limited understanding of python and coding so far (just began) I am finding it very hard to see whats going on.

Now heres my question:

I know that i can send a simple string of code by writing this in blender, which worked for me:

```
import socket
host ='127.0.0.1'
port = 50007
msg = '345;'
s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
     s.connect((host,port))
     s.send(msg.encode())
```

And i know that i can make this code to get e.g the coordinates from my object:

```
import bge

def main():

   cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
   owner = cont.owner
   vel = owner.getVelocity()
   x = (vel [0])
   y = (vel [1])
   z = (vel [2])
   print (x+y+z)

main()
```

What I need to figure out is how to insert that information into my.send so I can receive it in Pure Data.
I have looked at websites on how to make this work but havent found what i needed. I am wondering if anyone has some good sources that might concern this, or if anyone knows how to integrate my owner.getVelocity() into the tcp message?

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you are encouraged to post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok! i will do that now then!:)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

I think I Solved it my self, I am getting my dataflow in PD now.

if anyone is interested this is the code:

```
import bge
import socket




cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner
vel = owner.getVelocity()

x = (vel [0])
y = (vel [1])
z = (vel [2])

added = x+y+z
print (added)

tsr = str(added)     
tsr += ';'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 50007
msg = '123456;'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))

s.send(tsr.encode())

s.shutdown(0)

s.close()
```

thanks for your time!

Andreas